# How to reach an array that an array of pointers points to?

Tags: arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to create an array of pointers, in which each pointer points to the start of an array (which is basically also an array of pointers)
I've tried the following:

```
//declarations:
int* all_paths_of_size_r= (int*)malloc(p_num*sizeof(int)); //p_num is the number of possible paths of size r
int* path = (int*)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
```

I'm using both of them in  recurrsive function in which i wrote:

```
*(all_paths_of_size_r + place_in_arr) = path[0];
free(path);
place_in_arr++;
adds++; // this is an int that tells me if there are no more possible paths of size r so that i can free the last malloc I created within the function
int* path = (int*)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
if(adds==how_many_paths_of_size_r_could_be_generated_of_set_N(r, N)) //set N is the numbers from 0 to N-1
    free(path);
```

now, I'm trying to reach each one of these arrays that are pointed at by all_paths_of_size_r (I mean I’m trying to reach every array to check if the last number of it is x), how do I do so?